# Combine an array of objects for the same value in Objective-C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, compare

I have an array of custom object name `finalBarListArray` with entity `BarCodeSKULists` (refer to the attachment 1) which contains `sales_sub_category_name (string type)`, `count (int type)` and an array of another custom object name `arrayBarCodeSKUList (BarCodeSKUList)` (refer to the attachment 2/3/4).

Please see the below screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I need to create an array and have to check if there will be same `sales_sub_category_name` value then need to add their `arrayBarCodeSKUList` in one.

Like in above array `finalBarListArray`, there are three elements with `sales_sub_category_name 'ENVY 17', 'ENVY 15' & 'ENVY 15'`, so I need to merge second and third element into one for second index of array. It means Output should have only two elements, where first element should have (`count = 1` & one `arrayBarCodeSKUList`) and the second element should have (`count = 2` & two `arrayBarCodeSKUList`).

Comment: what's the object type of the element in the new array? still "BarCodeSKULists"? and what's you meaning of  the second element sholud have two arraybarCodeSDKList?

Comment: BarCodeSKULists is my modal class name, inside this entity I have  another modal class name BarCodeSKUList and an array 'arrayBarCodeSKUList'.

Comment: `(count = 1 & one arrayBarCodeSKUList)...(count = 2 & two arrayBarCodeSKUList)` you meant `arrayBarCodeSKList` will be of count = 1 and of count = 2, no? Not tested, but: https://pastebin.com/5h5tfrfz ?

Comment: @LarmeThanks for your response. I mean the final array should have two elements, where one will be sales_sub_category_name = "ENVY 17", Count = 1 & arrayBarCodeSKUList = 1 and the other will be sales_sub_category_name = "ENVY 15", Count = 2 & two arrayBarCodeSKUList array of BarCodeSKUList objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following method to merge the array of custom objects, which has same `sales_sub_category_names`.

```
- (NSArray *)mergeDuplicate {

    NSMutableDictionary *mergedDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    // Use sales_sub_category_name value as a key for the dictioanry.

    [finalBarListArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(BarCodeSKULists * _Nonnull object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        id existingItem = [mergedDictionary valueForKey:object.sales_sub_category_name];
        if (existingItem) {
            // If object exist then check that type is NSMutableArray or not
            if ([existingItem isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]) {

                // If yes then append with existing array
                [existingItem addObject:object];
                mergedDictionary[object.sales_sub_category_name] = existingItem;
            } else if ([existingItem isKindOfClass:[BarCodeSKULists class]]) {
                // Else if the object is `BarCodeSKULists ` class then create array and added previous item and current item into one array
                NSMutableArray *itemList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:existingItem, object, nil];
                mergedDictionary[object.sales_sub_category_name] = itemList;
            }
        } else {
            // If it is first time then add it to the dictionary
            mergedDictionary[object.sales_sub_category_name] = object;
        }

    }];

    NSLog(@"%@", mergedDictionary.allValues);
    return mergedDictionary.allValues;
}
```

**`mergedDictionary.allValues` will give the expected array of items**

**Update :**

As per the discussion.

```
- (NSArray *)mergeDuplicate:(NSMutableArray *) list{

    NSMutableDictionary *mergedDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

    // Use sales_sub_category_name value as a key for the dictioanry.

    [list enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(BarCodeSKUList * _Nonnull object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {

        BarCodeSKUList *existingItem = [mergedDictionary valueForKey:object.sales_sub_category_name];
        if (existingItem) {
            [existingItem.arrayBarCodeSKUList addObjectsFromArray:object.arrayBarCodeSKUList];
            mergedDictionary[object.sales_sub_category_name] = existingItem;
        } else {
            // If it is first time then add it to the dictionary
            mergedDictionary[object.sales_sub_category_name] = object;
        }

    }];


    return mergedDictionary.allValues;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @Subramanian, I have tested the above soln but this is giving me the result in key/value pairs (due to dictionary) instead of array of custom objects format. How to achieve this?

Comment: The reason is I need to pass the data from custom array objects to the table sections & their respected rows for same sub_category_name. Thanks !

Comment: From dictionary you can get the array of values `mergedDictionary.allValues`. After code I have mentioned that also

Comment: @AnandGautam Now I have changed the function return type as `NSArray`

Comment: Okay I understand.. but here you have added a full class object of BarCodeSKULists according to the key 'sales_sub_category_name'. But as an output I just want to add arrayBarCodeSKUList (array of BarCodeSKUList Class) to the super array.

Comment: becos sales_sub_category_name is not hard code, it can be change at run time.

Comment: But you want to merge the data based on the `sales_sub_category_name`. If it changed `sales_sub_category_name ` value at runtime then you have to redo right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149986/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-subramanian).

Answer (score 1):

```
- (NSArray *)mergeObject{

    NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [_originArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(BarCodeSKULists*  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        id item = [dic objectForKey:obj.sales_sub_category_name];

        if (item) {
            BarCodeSKULists *list = (BarCodeSKULists *)item;
            [list.arrayBarCodeSKUList addObject:obj.BarCodeSKUList];
            list.count = (int)list.arrayBarCodeSKUList.count;
            dic[obj.sales_sub_category_name] = list;
        }
        else{
            dic[obj.sales_sub_category_name] = obj;
        }
    }];

    return dic.allValues;
}
```

Comment: @ColeThank you for your answer, it's working too. +1  :)